# XenForo запретить гостям оставлять сообщения

Tags: forum

Добрый день, столкнулся с такой проблемой что гости могут оставлять сообщения в некоторых темах. Хотя в группе "незарегистрированные" таких прав нету, даже если запрещаешь все права в данной группе, ничего не меняется. В настройка ничего нету, что касается прав пользователей. Самое странное что не во всех темах можно создавать гостям сообщения.

`XenForo 1.5.14`

Comment: Отдельных настроек прав в каждом разделе/форуме случайно нет?

Comment: @Visman есть, но там тоже полазил, не менял права для незарегистрированных